# AWS Neptune find id of all the vertices connected to a particular vertice

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am trying to get ids of all the vertices connected to a particular vertex. Where id is not "id" property, instead its the id of the node (T.id)

```
g.V().has(T.id, "id1").both("is")
==>v[id2]
==>v[id3]
==>v[id4]
```

But when I am trying to get only the ids of the vertices I don't get any.

```
g.V().has(T.id, "id1").both("is").values("id")
g.V().has(T.id, "id1").both("is").id
```

What I want is something like below:

```
==>id2
==>id3
==>id4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly,
You can use this:

```
g.V("id1").both("is").id()
```

Anyway if you want to get the id you can use `id()` step